# Value is not setting to the KO observable variable on Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, knockout.js, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

1. When making the ajax call to the controller method, I am getting the null values. I'm new to the knockout and appreciated your help on the the issues. I'm placing this js code in external file and am calling the loginmethod function on button click. There is no form tag as per the requirements.
2. How I can include the knockout unobstrucive validation for the below snippets?

```
var ViewModel = function () {

    //Make the self as 'this' reference
    var self = this;

    //Declare observable which will be bind with UI
    self.UserName = ko.observable("");
    self.Password = ko.observable("");
    self.RememberMe = ko.observable(false);
    self.ReturnUrl = ko.observable("");

    //The Object which stored data entered in the observables
    var CustData = {
        UserName: self.UserName,
        Password: self.Password,
        RememberMe: self.RememberMe,
        ReturnUrl : self.ReturnUrl,
    };

    //Declare an ObservableArray for Storing the JSON Response
    self.LoginMethod = function () {

        //Ajax call to Insert the Customer record
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8089/Home/SignIn/",
            data: ko.toJSON(CustData), //Convert the Observable Data into JSON
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("failed");
                console.log("data");
            }
        });

        //Ends Here
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Check this out. http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/AwPDz/ I believe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: "I'm getting null values" - Where ?  The server-side controller or somewhere else ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In server side controller am getting the null values.

Comment: shouldn't we use paranthesis to access the values in observable?
var CustData = {
        UserName: self.UserName(),
        Password: self.Password(),
        RememberMe: self.RememberMe(),
        ReturnUrl : self.ReturnUrl(),
    };